# Compiler error when inheriting from ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#

```
class Test<string, T> : System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>
```

The above code returns the two errors:

- CS1001 Identifier expected
- CS1003 Syntax error, ',' expected

However, capitalising the `string` within Test produces no errors.

```
class Test<String, T> : System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>
```

---

**Can anybody explain as to why the compiler would be producing these errors when `string` is lowercase, but not when uppercase?**

Comment: Your `Test` class should only have one parameter: `class Test<T>: ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>`. `string` is a reserved keyword. In `class Test<String, T>` `String` is just another type parameter and does not refer to the `System.String` class.

Comment: `String` is a generic parameter not the `String` class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `class Test<string, T>` you're attempting to define a new type argument and name that type argument `string`.  `string` isn't a valid identifier for a type, because it's a reserved word in the language.  `String` isn't a reserved word in the language; it's a valid name for you to give your new type argument, so the code works.

Or at least, "works" in the sense that you've now named your new type alias `String`.  But you don't actually want to do that; you don't want to have a new type argument *named* `String`, you just want to have the key of your dictionary be a `String`, so simply *don't define a new type argument at all*:

```
class Test<T> : System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>
```

On a related note,  you probably shouldn't be inheriting from `ConcurrentDictionary` at all.  It's not a type that was designed to be inherited from.  You probably just want to compose one, and have your own type that simply has a ConcurrentDictionary as a field.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Very enlightening and well explained. I'll heed your advice in terms of inheriting and have it as a private field.

Comment: @Chawin Whether the program functions properly or not in a program using multiple threads is dependant on a whole bunch of things, based on the specifics of what you're doing throughout the whole program, not just whether or not the class is static.